# how to address "make: protoc: Command not found"

Tags: centos, makefile, protocol-buffers, caffe

I'm installing Caffe on a CentOS system over which I do not have administrative privileges. When I attempt to compile, I encounter the following message:

```
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
make: protoc: Command not found
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc] Error 127
```

What I have done so far is the following:

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/BVLC/caffe.git
cd caffe
cp Makefile.config.example Makefile.config
# Uncomment CPU_ONLY := 1.
# Include the following lines:
# INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial/
# LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial
pico Makefile.config
virtualenv caffe
source caffe/bin/activate
pip install protobuf
pip install scikit-image
make all
```

How should I address this error?

Answer (score 2):

Since you lack administrative privileges you can either

- ask your admin to install the [protobuf](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23552166/dir/centos_6/com/protobuf-2.5.0-16.1.x86_64.rpm.html) and [protobuf-compiler](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23552167/dir/centos_6/com/protobuf-compiler-2.5.0-16.1.x86_64.rpm.html) packages.
- compile it yourself and install the binaries in your `~/bin` directory.

For the latter, this page (*[Install google protocol buffers (protoc, protobuf) on CentOS 6 (linux)](http://tech.yipp.ca/linux/install-google-protocol-buffers-linux/)*) hints that it may be as simple as using the `--prefix=$HOME` option on the configure script.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu, if you would have administrative rights, you could do

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler-grpc
```